# Random pictures from array

Tags: java, arrays, image, javafx

I am trying to build a program that, first display random 4 pictures from a folder at the top of the pane, then display one of these pictures at the bottom of the pane.

I build everything right, but it seems that there is an error where the four pictures are displayed but the bottom one is different from the others.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {

    StackPane st = new StackPane();
    HBox hb4 = new HBox(25);
    HBox hb1 = new HBox(25);

    // random nubers array
    int[] rndN = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rndN.length; i++)
        rndN[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 66);

    ImageView[] imgVV = new ImageView[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < imgVV.length; i++) {
        imgVV[i] = new ImageView(new Image(rndN[i] + ".png"));
        imgVV[i].setFitHeight(220);
        imgVV[i].setFitWidth(210);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imgVV));

    hb4.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    hb1.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

    hb4.getChildren().addAll(imgVV);
    hb1.getChildren().add(imgVV[1]);

    st.getChildren().addAll(hb4, hb1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(st, 1250, 700);
    arg0.setScene(scene);
    arg0.setTitle("4 in 1");
    arg0.show();
}
```

and picture from the program:
[4pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1w7o.png)

I would like if you can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Why is your Array of size 5 if you only want 4 pictures? If I understand it correctly `hb4.getChildren().addAll(imgVV);` in your case would add 5 pictures.

Comment: One node can have only one parent. When you call this `hb1.getChildren().add(imgVV[1]);` you change a parent of `imgVV[1]` to bottom pane. So it removes from top

Comment: Oh, that new information to me, thanks.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Create a copy of `ImageView` you wish to add to bottom pane

Comment: hint: an `Image` can be shared across different `ImageView`s

Comment: See if you can use some ideas from [here](https://github.com/sedj601/CardMatchingFX/tree/master/src/cardmatchingfx).